# Is there any equivalent of Chronometer setBase() method in c#?

Tags: c#, android, mono, xamarin, chronometer

I am developing app using xamarin in c#. Converting java code I notice that my chronometer doesn't have setBase() method. Is there any equivalent of this method in c#?

Comment: all `setXXX()` stuff is replaced by proper properties in C# in Xamarin. the `setXXX()` and `getXXX()` stuff is a lame workaround to java's lack of real properties. It does nothing but make code look ugly. C#, since it's a beautiful language, has beautiful constructs, hence properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  The Xamarin [Chronometer](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3AAndroid.Widget.Chronometer%2FP) class has a `Base` property you can set.

```
public virtual long Base { get; set; }
```